# i want to scrape values from the graph using python and beautiful soup

Tags: web-crawler, screen-scraping

here is website where i want to scrape the value from graph [click here](https://pricebaba.com/mobile/oppo-a83-4gb-64gb) click here to view the graph
[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tJMt.png)
here is code which **scrapes** other data from that page
like specification and related products
and also collect different sellers from the page i am working on final year project.
to complete the project i only need to scrap the values from graph

```js
def specification(self, request):
  product_name = list()
  product_price = list()
  image_source = list()
  product_href = list()
  rows = list()
  table_colum_1 = list()
  table_colum_2 = list()
  stores = list()
  store_redirect_links = list()
  other_prices = list()
  href = request.GET.get('url')
  l = href
  scrap1 = self.page_load(href)
  content1 = BeautifulSoup(scrap1.text, "html.parser")
  containers = content1.findAll("li", {
    "class": "crsl__itm prd-sldr__itm prd-sldr__itm--s"
  })
  for container in containers:
    name = container.find("div", {
      "class": "prdp-ttl"
    }).get_text()
  print(name)
  price = container.find("div", {
    "class": "prdp-prc price"
  }).get_text()
  print(price)
  source = container.findAll('div')[1]
  print(source)
  source = source.img['data-src']
  href = container.find('a')['href']
  product_name.append(name)
  product_price.append(price)
  image_source.append(source)
  product_href.append(href)
  data_id = content1.find('div', {
    'class': 'crd prd-prmry-crd'
  })
  id = data_id.find('li', {
    'class': 'float--right'
  })
  id = id.find('input', {
    'class': 'aPC'
  })
  pid = id['data-pid']
  info = content1.find('ul', {
   'class': 'nav soft-half--top soft-half--left quick-spec nav--vtop three-cols'
  })
  info_rows = info.findAll('li')
  for row in info_rows:
    rows.append(row.text)
  
  
  
  name = content1.find("h1", {
    "class": "bold txt-xl"
  }).text
  name = name.replace(' Price', '')
  price = content1.find("div", {
    "class",
    "txt-xl bold spcolor lowestPrice"
  }).text
  source = content1.find("li", {
    "class",
    'crsl__itm gllry__itm gllry__itm--s sgllryimgLnkCnt'
  })
  source = source.img['data-src']
  
  if content1.find('div', {
      'class': 'crd-hdr bg--warning'
    }) == None:
    r = content1.find('div', {
      'class': "push-half--bottom"
    })
  if r.find('a') != None:
    redirect = r.find('a')['href']
  redirect_name = r.text
  
  else :
    redirect_name = "out of stock"
  redirect = ""
  
  else :
    redirect_name = "out of stock"
  redirect = ""
  multiple_stores = content1.findAll('div', {
    'class': 'invt__itm inventoryListItem '
  })
  for store in multiple_stores:
    n = store.find('div', {
      'class',
      'soft-half--bottom'
    })
  store_name = n.img['src']
  store_redirect_link = n.find('a')['href']
  other_price = store.find('span', {
    'class',
    'price invt__prc'
  }).text
  if other_price == "-":
    other_price = "Not Available "
  stores.append(store_name)
  store_redirect_links.append(store_redirect_link)
  other_prices.append(other_price)
  tables = content1.findAll("table", {
    "class": "sp"
  })
  for table in tables:
    table_rows = table.findAll('tr')
  i = 0
  for tr in table_rows:
    if (i >= 1):
      colum1 = tr.findAll("td")[0].text
  colum2 = tr.findAll("td")[1].text
  
  table_colum_1.append(colum1)
  table_colum_2.append(colum2)
  i = i + 1
  spec = {
    'index1': range(0, len(product_name)),
    'product_name': product_name,
    'product_price': product_price,
    'image_source': image_source,
    'product_href': product_href,
    'name': name,
    'price': price,
    'source': source,
    'redirect': redirect,
    'redirect_name': redirect_name,
    'pid': pid,
    'index': range(0, len(rows) - 1),
    'rows': rows,
    'total_stores': range(0, len(stores)),
    'stores': stores,
    'store_redirect_links': store_redirect_links,
    'other_prices': other_prices,
    'total_spec': range(0, len(table_colum_1)),
    'table_colum_1': table_colum_1,
    'table_colum_2': table_colum_2,
    'l_p': l
  }
  
  return render(request, 'product_details.html', spec)
```

now but i want to **scrape** the graph values to display on my page

Comment: Your question would be easier to read if you included the images directly, rather than as external links. Also, is your question about image processing (estimating a trend within a 2D image), or about extracting values from within a block of html text? Thanks.

Comment: not image processing sir extract values from  graph

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap